# Adding symlink to /usr/bin

Tags: terminal, symlink

I'm trying to add python3 to my path by adding a symlink but it's erroring and I'm not sure why.

```
/usr/bin $ sudo su
sh-3.2# ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3  /usr/bin/python3
ln: /usr/bin/python3: Operation not permitted

sh-3.2# whoami
root

sh-3.2# ls -la | head -n 2
total 139064
drwxr-xr-x  977 root   wheel     31264 24 Jul  2018 .
```

*** Edit ***

I have symlinked from `/usr/local/bin/python3` so that's fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/usr/bin` is, as a lot of directories installed by default, protected by SIP and can't be modified by any user. There are ways to disable SIP, but the better approach is to use the directories beneath `/usr/local` for user-installed things

```bash
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/
```

If `/usr/local/bin` is not early in your `PATH`, run `sudo nano /etc/paths` to add it as the first line.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to know what directories are protected by SIP from the command line? @nohillside

Comment: @AJP Sure, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899. Or use `ls -Ol` (that's the letter O)